# how to show a button on a webview without mixing the contents

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to create a button and an edittext on the webview and both should be located at rear of the page. In my attemps as posted below, I managed to setup both of the button and the edittext area on the webview, but the problem is that, both of the button and the edittext area are shadowed or covered by the contents of the web page. Is there any way to avoid mixing the contents with those elements.

JavaCode:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page00);

    webView00 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView00);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn);
    etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_edittext);

    webView00.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView00.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    webView00.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());

    webView00.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.webapptest01.WebAppTest01$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView00"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Go!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/url_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:minWidth="220dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Used `FrameLayout` and and make one `LinearLayout` and add your buttons on this `LinearLayout` and set gravity as bottom to this `Linearlayout`

Comment: should i use FrameLayout instead of the relativeLayout i am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way that keeps it as a single `RelativeLayout` (no nested layouts) and makes use of the [`android:layout_above`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_above) attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.webapptest01.WebAppTest01$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Go!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/url_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:minWidth="220dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/url_edittext" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks it worked now, but i have some questions please answer them if you can:1)how can I achieve the same results but using FrameLayout and LinearLayout as you first suggested? 2)why my question is being under rated(voted down)?

Comment: I didn't suggest using a FrameLayout and LinearLayout - that was someone else. I (of course :) ) think my solution is better - it only uses 1 parent layout. Why you are being downvoted? I don't know, I didn't downvote you. It could be because your code formatting was not perfect (although I have seen much worse) or people think it's a simple question and you did not "try" hard enough (I have seen much worse questions too). The people of StackOverflow can be fickle, don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use frame layout instead of Relative Layout.

Here is your xml code you can add this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/url_edittext" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:text="Go!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/url_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:minWidth="220dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```